# One TextField for two attributes with DataTransformer

Tags: php, symfony, attributes, field

I have searched a lot on google but I have no idea of how to solve my problem.
I have an Entity `EntreeListe` which contains two attributes `rayon` and `produit`. I would like that the user enter in a text field : `Rayon : Produit`.

So, I add two DataTransformer on my textfield `produit`

```
$builder->get('produit')
    ->addModelTransformer(new StringToProduitTransformer($this->manager));
$builder->get('produit')
    ->addModelTransformer(new StringToRayonTransformer($this->manager));
```

So that I can transform `explode(' : ', $string)[0]` into a `Rayon` and `explode(' : ', $string)[1]` into a `Produit`.

The problem is that, when I submit the form, the parameter passed to `reverseTransform` of `StringToProduitTransformer` is not a string but a `Rayon` because the transformation of `StringToRayonTransformer` is already done.

I don't know if I'm clear, so just ask questions. Any suggestions is welcome :).

What I want is to have the string passed to the two reverseTransform... So have multiple DataTransformer for one field.

Or is there another way to do this ? To complete two attributes with one input ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Other idea is to use lifecycle callback on entity with additional field not mapped to database.

Comment: What is the objective of this ? I can create an attribute taking the input string, but how with the lifecycle callback can I complete the object Rayon and Produit ? I don't see.

Comment: Just before update/save your entity you can set values for the two properties based on another property, and off course when you fetch entity you can set value for not mapped property based on the two properties.

Comment: I see what you mean now, but this is not very elegant... Put a field in a class to fill another class after the DataTransformer...